# "Favorites" feature using cookies and sessions (PHP & CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, session, codeigniter, cookies

I'm trying to implement a "favorites" feature to my site and I was wondering on how to go about storing this data. What I'd like to do if possible is have the user favorite things and store it in the DB - that way I could use the data to personalize search results.

I'm also trying to have it so there is a smooth transition between favorites in a non logged in state to a logged in one (allow the user to save favorites anonymously but if logs in transfer/ask to transfer those to his account)

How would I be able to store this data for long periods of time? I'm currently using DB encrypted sessions and I was thinking of extending the session time or setting it to not expire. That would probably lead me to some security issues no?

I'd appreciate the help,

Cheers.

Comment: What do you mean by "... have the user favorite things..."? What exactly are "things"? Pages? Categories? Also, you might want to store this data in the database, since sessions (even when set to not expire) can still expire. Don't trust cookies to hold that sort of data. Plus, do you want favorites to still be there if they log on using a different computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if i understand, what you want is that a registered user can set "something" as a favorite, since this is a M:N relationship (strictly from a database point of view), i would recommend a table storing these relationships, i.e. Supposing you have a user and a topic table, the SQL would like similar to this:

```
create table favorite(user_id integer not null references user, topic_id integer not null references topic);
```

At least this is what most DB books will tell you to do. If you don't have a user table (i suppose you have one for that "something" you want to mark as favorite), you could just store the id you assign to the user whenever s/he logs into the system. Hope to have been of help.

Answer (score 1):

Create actual users out of your anonymous sessions. Persist them in the database without login credentials and associate favorites or whatever else you store with their user ID. If they sign up before they clear their cookies, you just add their login/profile into to the existing user ID and all the favorites they've created are already in the right spot. One system for both logged in and logged out users, not two.